# get textarea value then post using ajax laravel 5

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

im new to laravel so how do i get the 
output then get the value of the input in the textarea then save it to db using ajax if i have
car1 
car2 already
then if i put car 3 in textarea it should add the car3

view

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        asdf
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="cars"/>
    <button class="create-car"> Create </button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>          
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function get (){
        var g = document.getElementbyID("cars").value;
    }
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.get('/').success(function(data) {
                data.forEach(function(car) {
                    console.log(car);
                    $('body').append(car.name + "<br/>");                       
                });
            }); 
            $('.create-car').click(function() {
                var data = {
                    /*"name": "Honda",
                    "owner": "Someone"*/
                    "name": g.getValue(),
                    "owner": "zxc"

                }
                $.post('/', data);
            });     
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

route

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return App\Car::all();
});

Route::post('/', function () {
    return App\Car::create(Request::all());
});

Route::get('/ajax', function () {
    return view('index');
});
```

Comment: Your code includes two copies of your routes, please show your view.

Comment: sorry my bad ,edited already

Comment: Where are you experiencing issues? Are the cars not saving successfully?  Is the GET request not returning any data? Or both..?

Comment: both are not working